# Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{2^n}\int_a^b \cos^n(x+\frac{\pi}{4})\, dx $

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sqrt{2^n}\int_a^b \cos^n \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\,dx$$
>   knowing that the set of integration $[a,b]$ is included in $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Now, my attempt was to first notice that the function that we have to integrate is: $\cos^n(x+\frac{\pi}{4})$ and I was thinking that I can use this trigonometric identity :$$\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)+\sin(a)\sin(b)\,,$$ after which I can apply the reduction formula for $\cos^n(x)$. Is this the way to start ?

Comment: I would try the following: for odd values of $n$, i.e. $n=2k+1$ we have $\int \cos^nxdx=\int \cos^{2k}x \cos xdx=\int (1-t^2)^k dt$ and for even $n=2k$ we have $\int \cos^{2k}x dx=\int \left(\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}\right)^k dx$. I'm not sure if it leads anywhere, but it's just the first thing that comes to mind. Btw, if the limit exists, it suffices to calculate it just for odd values of $n$.

Comment: Can you please clarify if the integration is over $[0,\pi/2]$ or just any closed interval contained in $(0,\pi/2)$?

Comment: It is $(0,\pi/2)$

Comment: I just checked right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that on $\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ we have

$$1 \geq \sqrt{2}\cos\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right) \geq -1$$

thus by dominated convergence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{2^n}\int_a^b \cos^n\left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\:dx = \int_a^b 0 \:dx = 0$$

for any $[a,b] \subset \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$